# Eliminar archivos txt de una carpeta y dejar solo los 5 mas recientes

Tags: python

A ver si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacer esto.
Tengo una carpeta con varios *txt* , con estos nombres:

```
1.1.1.1-03-05-2023.txt
1.1.1.1-02-05-2023.txt
1.1.1.1-01-05-2023.txt
1.1.1.1-31-04-2023.txt
1.1.1.1-30-04-2023.txt
1.1.1.1-29-04-2023.txt
1.1.1.1-28-05-2023.txt
```

Quiero un script que entre a esa carpeta (por ejemplo carpeta que se llame `1.1.1.1`, y elimine todos los dejando solo los 5 con las fechas mas recientes (las fechas ya aparecen en el nombre de los txts).

Comment: Ordenas por fecha y omites los 5 primeros (o 5 últimos, dependiendo de como ordenes)

Comment: Voto por el cierre de esta pregunta por que está pidiendo, de manera directa, que escriban código por él.

Answer (score 5):

Necesitas escribir una función que extraiga la fecha del nombre del archivo, por ejemplo:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def extraer_fecha(nombre_archivo):
    fecha_str = nombre_archivo.split('-')[1:4]
    fecha_str = '-'.join(fecha_str).replace('.txt', '')
    return datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Como ves, en esa función se procesa el nombre del fichero para extraer las cadenas que representan el día, mes y año (separadas por "-") para después concatenarlas en una cadena que solo tenga dia-mes-año y finalmente convertirlas en un objeto de tipo `datetime`. La gracia de hacer esto es que esos objetos ya se pueden comparar unos con otros para ver cuál es "mayor" (que en el caso de `datetime` indicaría una fecha posterior), a diferencia de las cadenas que solo se pueden comparar alfabéticamente.

Gracias a esa función puedes ordenar todos los archivos por fechas, simplemente pasando dicha función como parámetro `key=` a la función estándar `sorted()`, así:

```
import glob

carpeta = "1.1.1.1"
archivos = glob.glob(carpeta + '*.txt')
archivos_ordenados = sorted(archivos, key=extraer_fecha, reverse=True)
```

La función `sorted()` es muy potente porque es muy genérica. Te ordena cualquier cosa si le dices cómo compararlas entre sí. Al pasarle `key=extraer_fecha` lo que hace `sorted()` es invocar a esa función para cada elemento de la lista, y el resultado de esa invocación será lo que use para comparar un elemento con otro (y por tanto para ordenarlos). Así que en lugar de comparar las cadenas (nombres de fichero), comparará los objetos `datetime` retornados por `extraer_fecha()` y ordenará la lista de nombres según esos objetos.

La lista resultante contendrá cadenas, pero ordenadas por la fecha que representan. Al usar `reverse=True` la ordenación será descendente.

En la lista resultante, los 5 primeros son los más recientes. Así que puedes saltártelos en el bucle que borra archivos:

```py
import os

for archivo in archivos_ordenados[5:]:
    os.remove(archivo)
    print(f'Archivo eliminado: {archivo}')
```

Yo antes de ejecutar esto comentaría la línea `os.remove()` para que no borre nada en realidad. Así podrás ver los que borraría. Si todo va bien, la descomentas.

Comment: Una buena forma de no fomentar la holgazanería y ganar votos positivos de buena manera sería crear una pregunta+respuesta donde se demuestre el esfuerzo. Mientras tanto, voto negativo esta respuesta por que fomenta la holgazanería y compensar esta "recompensa". Perdon Abulafia, solo me aseguro de que el sitio sea justo y mantenga su calidad.

Comment: @Dante, me parece muy mal que castigues a quién ha escrito una buena respuesta y no te tomes la molestia de darle -1 a quién escribió tan _mala_ pregunta. En mi opinión, debes aprender a separar las cosas. De hecho, hay medallas para quienes escriben excelentes respuestas a terribles preguntas (chaleco salvavidas, bote salvavidas). Si no te gusta, simplemente no votes la respuesta, pero no castigues a la persona incorrecta.

Comment: Es una respuesta incompleta, no explica que hace el código. Además, he visto respuestas parecidas que han sido castigadas. Por que no en este caso? Y no es un castigo, quiero reducir el efecto de la recompensa. Y en este caso no es buena idea responder. Y tenés razón, voy a votar negativo también la pregunta. @jachguate

Comment: Si la respuesta no tuviese votos positivos, no hubiera votado.

Comment: Y estoy moderando el sitio, debo votar

Comment: Difiero en cuanto a que la respuesta es incompleta. Creo que da una explicación aceptable y el código se auto-explica también, pero al menos ahora si habría un motivo para darle un voto negativo a la respuesta: el creer realmente que es una mala respuesta. El hecho de que otras personas castiguen otras respuestas no debiera ser razón suficiente para castigar una respuesta. A veces, no emitir un voto también es válido, no lo olvides.

Comment: @DanteS. No me importa el voto negativo. Lo que me importa es proporcionar recursos que puedan ser útiles a quienes vengan en el futuro buscando respuestas. En ese sentido tampoco doy tanta importancia a la calidad de las preguntas. Creo que la calidad del sitio depende sobre todo de la calidad de las respuestas. En ese sentido sí que me preocupa el tema de que la respuesta no explica mucho. Es cierto, yo tiendo a explicar mucho las cosas y aquí no lo hice, por probar el estilo de "ir más al grano". Editaré la respuesta para añadir algún detalle

Comment: Repito, no es un castigo y no dije que fuera una mala respuesta. Casi nunca emito un voto, pero en este caso lo consideré una emergencia. @jachguate

Comment: @abulafia Me alegro de que no te importe, por que no quería atacarte. El problema, es que le respondiste a alguien que pide, de manera directa, que le escriban un script. Yo creo que si querías aportar, hubiera sido mejor una pregunta+respuesta nueva. Le hiciste la tarea a alguien, lo cual puede afectarlo negativamente y al sitio también. Además, como la pregunta quedó cerrada, tu respuesta se perderá :c Si haces una nueva pregunta+respuesta, estaré encantado de retractar mi voto negativo.